# TwoWayView cannot find ItemClickSupport

Tags: android

Okey, so i have added the compile code in my gradle file, using the 0.1.2 version (compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.2'). I can import org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView; and it works well. But now when i want to add ItemClickSupport for this view it cannot find it, i.e. this is not working import org.lucasr.twowayview.ItemClickSupport;.

Normally i would think something was wrong with the importing of the library, but since i can use the twowayview (for scrolling pictures horizontally) successfully i dont see where the problem is.

I have also tried updating the lib to the latest version 0.1.4 but the same issue is still persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the snapshot instead of the stable release (which is the old AdapterView implementation). The snapshot includes the ItemClickSupport class. https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view#snapshot